# Error Importing Pyro after source install for Anaconda release of Python

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I downloaded Pyro using source install instructions [here](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyro-ppl/dev/pyro-ppl.pdf) under the Install from source link because I was always told not to use `pip` when installing to an Anaconda installation.  When I try `import pyro` I get the attribute error below which does not make sense

```
import pyro
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-05a8cb49cc0d>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyro

  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyro\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyro.primitives import (clear_param_store, enable_validation, get_param_store, iarange, irange, module, param,

  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyro\primitives.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pyro.infer as infer

  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyro\infer\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pyro.infer.traceenum_elbo import JitTraceEnum_ELBO, TraceEnum_ELBO

  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyro\infer\traceenum_elbo.py", line 183, in <module>
    class BackwardSampleMessenger(pyro.poutine.messenger.Messenger):

AttributeError: module 'pyro.poutine' has no attribute 'messenger'
```

This doesn't make much sense because in the `poutine` folder I have the `messenger` file and it has the Class `Messenger` so line 183 `class BackwardSampleMessenger(pyro.poutine.messenger.Messenger)` in the `traceenum_elbo.py` file should be working.

Comment: the 'pyro' tag is not for this particular library. It is for the Pyro remote objects library.

Comment: ok thanks.  which tag should I be using? PyTorch?  anywhere not sure why it is working now and I didn't fix anything, or maybe i did.

Comment: pytorch would be the correct tag